# Select combo item in Me.MyDataGridView.Rows(myRow).Cells(myCells)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, selectedvalue

I seek for help on this issue. I found a lot of questions in forums, but mostly unanswered or with "solutions" they don't work (reported by other users, I tried them too).

I simply would like to **set a value** from a list of values added to a ComboBoxCell in DataGridview, but it always ends up on "*datagridviewcomboboxcell value is not valid*" error

I tried (according to answers in forums I found):

1)

```
Me.MyDataGridView.Rows(myRow).Cells("myColumn").Value = "MyStringOrValue"
```

2)

```
CType(Me.MyDataGridView("MyColumn", Me.MyDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value = "MyStringOrValue
```

3)

```
cell.Value = cell.Items.Item(1)
```

4)

```
Dim cell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = Me.MyDataGridView.Rows(Me.MyDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1).Cells("MyColumn")
cell.DisplayMember = CType(Me.MyDataGridView.Columns("MyColumn"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DisplayMember
cell.ValueMember = CType(Me.MyDataGridView.Columns("MyColumn"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).ValueMember
cell.Value = cell.Items.Item(1)
```

5) Another edit: Counting cell items works, so THE PROBLEM is still, that it says, that cell.items.item(i) is not datatype-wise compactible with anything in cell.items - which is a mystery to me...

```
MsgBox("cell items = " & cell.Items.Count)
```

...returns "6" as it should

I appreciate any help. There has to be a way to select an item.

Regards,

Libor

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice.  If this doesn't work, you may need to post more code to show how you are creating / using this `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`.

```
Dim cell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = Me.MyDataGridView.Rows(myRow).Cells("myColumn")
cell.Value = cell.Items(0)
```

Comment: I tried this one already, including a variation with "cell.Items.Item(1)". Unfortunately, I get still the same error. I think one has to first create or link combo stuff for the DatagridviewcomboboxCell.